# document.all is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am working on an old project for maintenance. I found that `document.all` is not working in Firefox 25. And I am getting the error below.

```
TypeError: document.all.TabularDataControlAttivitta.object is undefined
```

And my sample code is:

```
document.all.TabularDataControlProj.object.Filter = 'COMPANYCODE=' + compValue;
document.all.TabularDataControlProj.object.Reset();
document.getElementById('cmbActivity_' + rowNo).options.length = 1;
if (document.getElementById('cmbProject_' + rowNo).options.length > 0) {
    for (var i = document.getElementById('cmbProject_' + rowNo).options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        document.getElementById('cmbProject_'+rowNo).options[i] = null;
    }
}
if (document.all.TabularDataControlProj.recordset.recordcount > 0) {
    document.all.TabularDataControlProj.recordset.movefirst;
}
pOption = new Option('-Select-', -1);
document.getElementById('cmbProject_' + rowNo).add(pOption);
while (document.all.TabularDataControlProj.recordset.eof == false) {
    Optionp = new Option((document.all.TabularDataControlProj.recordset.fields(0) + ' - ' + document.all.TabularDataControlProj.recordset.fields(2)), document.all.TabularDataControlProj.recordset.fields(0));
    document.getElementById('cmbProject_' + rowNo).add(Optionp);
    document.getElementById('cmbProject_' + rowNo).selectedIndex = indxAct;
    document.all.TabularDataControlProj.recordset.movenext;
    }
}
```

Any patch or solution for this? Because it's very difficult to edit the entire project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.all` is non-standard. It was a Microsoft-specific feature that they added to IE. Most other browsers have never supported it.

Even in IE it is now deprecated. You should not be using it.

(your old project must be very old, because this has been the case for quite some time now)

For most cases, you can use `document.getElementById()` instead.

If you're using `document.all` to get an element using it's ID value then `document.getElementById()` is a direct replacement.

If you're using `document.all` to get an element some other way, then I recommend switching to getting it by ID (add an ID if necessary).

I note that the way you're using the element makes it look like it may be an activeX control? (ie I see stuff like `.object.Filter`, `.recordset.movefirst`, etc)

If that is the case, then you need to be aware that Firefox does not support activeX controls at all. They are also specific to IE. If it is an activeX control and you need it to work in Firefox then unfortunately, you probably have quite a lot of rewriting ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

`Document.all`
    Provides access to all elements with an id. This a legacy non-standard interface, you should use the `document.getElementById()` method instead.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document

Comment: So this can be used like below . document.getElementById("x").recordset.fields(0)

Comment: @Krish R, that's incorrect. 
`document.all` retrieves the all collection just like `document.getElementsByTagName([wildcard])` does.
And you should retrieve it only once, because it's a Live node collection, and all the changes on the document tree are instantly reflected in it.
And all elements can be accessed either by their unique IDs or if anonymous, by their corresponding index of appearance in the current document.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, the problem is not with `document.all` not working (it does), it's with `document.all.TabularDataControlAttivitta.object` being undefined. This could be either because of application-specific reasons (you simply don't define an `object` expando), or because you have several elements with name or id equal to TabularDataControlAttivitta.