# Why is document.all defined but typeof document.all returns "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, dom

I was doing some research on JavaScript's `typeof` operator, and stumbled across the following weirdness:

> ## Exceptions
>
> All current browsers expose a non-standard host object `document.all` with type Undefined.
>
> ```
> typeof document.all === 'undefined';
> ```
>
> Although the specification allows custom type tags for non-standard exotic objects, it requires those type tags to be different from the predefined ones. The case of `document.all` having type tag `'undefined'` must be classified as an exceptional violation of the rules.

([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof))

I set up the following in my browser to test it:

```
console.log("typeof: " + typeof document.all);
console.log("toString: " + document.all);
```

It yielded:

```
typeof: undefined
toString: [object HTMLAllCollection]
```

So why is `document.all` like this? Since `document.all` is an object (defined in my browser), shouldn't `typeof` return `"object"`, not `"undefined"`?

Comment: Maybe this can answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350142/why-is-document-all-falsy Edit : This one gives more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880324/document-all-is-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: For Legacy stuff you would probably never use.

Comment: @Seblor neither of those say why `typeof document.all==="undefined"` though.

Comment: " document.all is non-standard. It was a Microsoft-specific feature that they added to IE. Most other browsers have never supported it." Basicaly, since it is not supported, I find it quite normal to not behave as it should.

Comment: you need to state the name of UA you are referring to

Comment: @BekimBacaj I don't think I would need to do so; the article says "all current browsers".

Comment: IE is quite current and it should return Object

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at this one from [Html Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-all)

> The `all` attribute must return an `HTMLAllCollection` rooted at the
>   `Document` node, whose filter matches all elements.
>
> The object returned for `all` has several unusual behaviors:
>
> 1. The user agent must act as if the ToBoolean abstract operation in JavaScript returns false when given the object returned for all.
> 2. The user agent must act as if the Abstract Equality Comparison algorithm, when given the object returned for `all`, returns `true` when
>      compared to the `undefined` and `null` values. (Comparisons using the
>      Strict Equality Comparison algorithm, and Abstract Equality
>      comparisons to other values such as strings or objects, are
>      unaffected.)
> 3. The user agent must act such that the typeof operator in JavaScript returns the string "undefined" when applied to the object returned for
>      `all`.

The third case is yours.

The rationale for this is compatibility with code designed for old browsers, as explained in a note in the specification:

> This violation is motivated by a desire for compatibility with two classes of legacy content: one that uses the presence of `document.all` as a way to detect legacy user agents, and one that only supports those legacy user agents and uses the `document.all` object without testing for its presence first.

Hope it will make sense for you.

Comment: Doesn't say _why_ it has those properties, though.

Comment: @StephenLeppik the standards rarely explain the reasons behind decisions.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Did you follow the link? There's a big green **Note** that explains why.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I saw that. I will accept an answer that has that note in it, with the link. After all, SO's end goal is building a knowledge base, and accessibility is important.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I added the relevant sentence from the note, it doesn't seem worth making a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround update:

```
document.all !== undefined;
>> true /*otherwise*/ false
```

Since https://html.spec.whatwg.org/ requires, that...

> The user agent must act as if the Abstract Equality Comparison algorithm, when given the object returned for all, returns true when compared to the undefined and null values.

but since...

> (Comparisons using the Strict Equality Comparison algorithm, and Abstract Equality comparisons to other values such as strings or objects, are **unaffected**.)

the use of ***Static Type Comparison Operator*** ( e.g.: **=== | !==** ) is perfectly safe to check if the *HTMLAllCollection* object is usable and\or present in the current UA client.

The ***Dynamic Type Comparison Operator*** will however continue to return a false absence as required by specification.

```
document.all != undefined;
>> false /*otherwise*/ false
```

A workaround (older)

```
"all" in document;
>> true /*otherwise*/ false
```

A more elaborate approach when dealing with third party code would be

```
delete document.all && "all" in document 
>> true /*otherwise*/ false
```