How to bypass document.all check?
I don't known how to bypass document.all on JavaScript check, the JavaScript code is
var check = "undefined" == typeof document.all && document.all

I don't known how to make document.all undefined and make it is function at the same time. Can you help me?
I don't know how to do this.

check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/40645120/218663

This is JavaScript code, why is the question tagged python?

unclear what you are asking.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

check will be true in ancient versions of IE. Is there a reason you want to emulate that discontinued browser?
